# Merging workbooks by tab name

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone is able to help.

I am looking at merging several workbooks in excel together but each workbook has 8-10 tabs that I don't need and I in fact only want a single tab, I have the following formula already which combines the workbooks, but I am unsure what to do to only combine the single tabs that I need, they are all the same name in each workbook.

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Which tab do you need? After your `For Eac Sheet ...` line, you could do say `I Sheet.Name = "SheetIWant" Then` to just copy the `Worksheets("SheetIWant")` data...

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry, I am a little confused. How would this look in the code?

Comment: "...I in fact only want a single tab,...." How do you know which tab you want? Does it have the same name in each workbook?

Comment: @BruceWayne, Yes they all have the same name

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

it's one of those cases where I'd use the *infamous* `On Error Resume Next` statement consciously and avoid looping through a collection (namely `Worksheets` one)

furthermore `ThisWorkbook` always references the workbook the running code resides in so there's no need for any `Workbook` type variable referring to it

```
Sub GetSheets()        
    Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True).Worksheets("SHEETNAME").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

just change `SHEETNAME` to you actual needed tab name

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to copy a specific sheet from each, the following should work (just tweak `SHEETNAME` to whatever that is)

```
Sub GetSheets()
dim mainWB as Workbook
Set mainWB = ThisWorkbook
Path = "C:\Users\dt\Desktop\dt kte\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sheet.Name = "SHEETNAME" then
        Sheet.Copy After:=mainWB.Sheets(1)
    End if 
  Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
  Loop
End Sub
```